# Merging of height balanced trees

Tags: algorithms, trees

$H_1$ and $H_2$ are two height balanced trees. How can they be merged such the time required for merging them is $O(\log n_1 + \log n_2)$ where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the number of nodes in the trees $H_1$ and $H_2$ respectively.

Every node of both the trees will store the height of sub-tree rooted at it.

Every element of $H_1$ is smaller than that of $H_2$.

One way of doing this will be as $H_1$ has all values less than $H_2$ then the entire tree $H_1$ can be made the child of the leftmost(smallest) node of $H_2$. Finding the leftmost (smallest) value will require $O(\log n_2)$ . Next rotations can be carried out on the newly constructed tree. But I cannot calculate how much time these rotations will take.

Is my approach towards solving the problem correct? If not , do point out my mistake....Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want to look at are AVL Trees (self balancing binary trees) [[wiki:AVL_Tree]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) to see the algorithm. Given that all elements of $H_1$ are smaller than those of $H_2$ the trees can be combined as is and only require a re-balancing step.

The time required for a rotation is kind of abstract and requires knowledge about how they are stored, from a computer science perspective this is usually done by pointers. So a rotation just switches over pointers. This is done in constant time depending on the type of tree (number of child nodes). In terms of $O$ notation it won't change anything, since it is a constant factor.

Comment: " the trees can be combined as is" . what does this mean? how can it be combined? Am I right in my approach??

Comment: Yes, basically what i meant with that is that $H_1$ can as a whole be attached to $H_2$. Given the left chid is always smaller than the parent, $H_1$ will be attached as a left child to the leftmost leaf of $H_2$, consequently about $log(n_2)$ nodes need to adjust their height, then a balancing step is required.

Comment: So basically I am correct in my approach ...